# Returning spatial data with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to return spatial data (ie Point) from database using Hibernate Spatial library (http://www.hibernatespatial.org/) using this WORKING approach...

```
    ... 
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("select location, distance(location, :requestPoint) from "+Event.class.getName());
    query.setParameter("requestPoint", requestPoint);

    List<?> rows = query.list();
    session.close();

    List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();

    for (Iterator<?> it = rows.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
       Object[] row = (Object[]) it.next();

       Event event = new Event();
       event.setLocation((Point) row[0]);
       event.setDistance((Double) row[1]);

       events.add(event);
    }

    return events;
```

but I would like to use something like this (use Event class constructor in select statment)...

```
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("select new Event(location, distance(location, :requestPoint)) from "+Event.class.getName());
    query.setParameter("requestPoint", requestPoint);

    List<Event> rows = query.list();
    session.close();

    return rows;
```

The problem is that the second approach gives me following exception...

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.jaygridley.aet.Event] [select new Event(location, distance(location, :requestPoint)) from com.jaygridley.aet.domain.Event]
```

but I cannot see why, because inside of my Event class I have a constructor...

```
public Event(Point location, Double distance) {
    this.location = location;
    this.distance = distance;
}
```

for clarity Event class has following properties...

```
@Column(name="LOCATION", columnDefinition = "MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY", nullable = false)
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
private Point location;

private Double distance;
```

I have checked return class for each column that Hibernate returns and it matches Point and Double. Does anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using Object instead of Point in constructor for location parameter and casting to Point afterwards in constructor body.

Answer (score 1):

My only guess is that your Event constructor signature is `Event(Point, Double)` and autoboxing is not working because you are trying to instance it like this `Event(location, distance(location, :requestPoint))` which args resolve to distance(Point, double).

I have been checking the function you are using and it [returns](http://www.hibernatespatial.org/) a `double` not a `Double`.

You may try with "`select new Event(location, new Double(distance(location, :requestPoint)))` but can't be certain.

It also can be that the function needs 2 Geometry as parameters, but I can't say if it is right.

Comment: already tried this and did not work. I think problem is with spatial location param, but cannot find what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the :requestPoint query parameter in the constructor call is the main problem. To test it try putting an actual double value there and see if it will compile. For example:

```
 Query query = session.createQuery("select new Event(location, 2.0) from "+Event.class.getName());
```

Just to see. If it does then it may mean that the compiler is trying to evaluate the signature of the constructor before evaluating the return type from the distance() function. Unfortunately I cannot suggest how to correct this if that is the case.

Comment: The problem is with location, not distance or :requestPoint, because when I try this Query query = session.createQuery("select new Event(distance(location, :requestPoint)) from "+Event.class.getName()); it is ok, but Query query = session.createQuery("select new Event(location) from "+Event.class.getName()); is not. Contructor for Event is public Event(Point location) {...}